# Output edge selection in geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes, edges, select

I want to procedurally select edges, based on their position criteria, and store that selection for later.

But can selection be an output attribute?

If not, is there any way to just output a visual highlight of the selected edges, like Sharp, Crease, Seam, even freestyle?

I don't want to change any geometry procedurally, just highlight / select.

Anything that I could see in edit mode for further manual edits after I apply the GN modifier.

In Blender generally, there doesn't seem to be many ways to manipulate edges procedurally. There are no edge groups/sets, not many nodes around edges stuff...

Comment: Are you talking about a geo node tool or geo node modifier?

Comment: I am talking about modifier. Don't know anything about geonode tool though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geometry Node Tools will help you with edit mode execution and selection. (Since you stated, that you would apply the modifier anyways.)
They act as an operator (and not a modifier) that is used in the workflow and changes the mesh directly "for further manual edits".

1. Go to the geometry nodes editor, set it to *tool* and create your node tree. In *tool* mode you have node that get or set the selection. Additional input attributes are converted to editable parameters. See the example node tree in the image. I named it *EdgeSelect*.
2. Go into edit mode in the 3D view. Choose your tool from the Geometry Tools dropdown in the 3D viewport menu or search for its name with <kbd>F3</kbd>.
3. Adjust the parameters of the operation.

[image: geo node tree and tool usage]

Comment: Cool, I didn't realize there was a hidden bucket in Blender with more geonodes :D This is just what I needed, thank you!